# How do I make java.util.logging work on App Engine Flexible Environment?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Most of my logging is not showing up when I use the Flexible Environment for a simple Java Servlet. Not at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer and not on the terminal when running Jetty locally.

Given this `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: java
env: flex
service: service-foo
runtime_config:
   jdk: openjdk8
   server: jetty9
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
  secure: always
beta_settings:
  java_quickstart: true
env_variables:
  JAVA_OPTS: >-
    -D.level=FINE
health_check:
  enable_health_check: false
```

And this Servlet `init()` method:

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);

    log.fine("Logging test. Level: fine."); // Not visible
    log.config("Logging test. Level: config."); // Not visible
    log.info("Logging test. Level: info."); // Visible
    log.warning("Logging test. Level: warning."); // Visible
    log.severe("Logging test. Level: severe."); // Visible
}
```

I see only this in the logs:

[image: screenshot]

I have no `appengine-web.xml` file in my application and no `logging.properties` file.

Note that even for the levels that do appear, they are NOT using the levels from the platform. There's a greyed out star next to the log entry and filtering the logs by a level such as `Warning` will exclude log messages I logged with that level.

Please do not suggest I use SLF4J, as some other posters on SO have ended up doing just to make this work. It's pure evil and shouldn't be necessary.